# jQuery show() function display inline. How?

Tags: jquery, css

I have some code like this now the problem is i want to show `li` display inline 
by default its display block and I'm not that good in jquery.
please help..

```
$('ul:first',this).parent().find('> a').addClass('active');
$('ul:first',this).show();
}).on('mouseout',function(e){
$(this).parent().removeClass('expanded');
$('ul:first',this).parent().find('> a').removeClass('active');
$('ul:first', this).hide();
```

Comment: why don't you use css?

Comment: I’ve chosen jQuery because it’s more efficient and universally supported.

Comment: this will be a mess on mobile , just FYI , you can't mouseover to get the element to show

Comment: If you are writing an HTML5 application, CSS is already supported

Comment: @user3063262 oh, bless your heart.

Comment: css is universally supported, even more so - no one blocks css, but they can block javascript

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works.

```
$('ul:first', this).parent().find('> a').addClass('active');
$('ul:first', this).css('display', 'inline');
}).on('mouseout', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('expanded');
    $('ul:first', this).parent().find('> a').removeClass('active');
    $('ul:first', this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use CSS. There's no need for doing this with JavaScript at all as you're already toggling the `.active` class, so in your CSS simply add:

```css
ul a {
    display: none;
}

ul a.active {
    display: inline;
}
```

Obviously `ul a` is a very generic selector and you may need to target it more specifically to the element you're wishing to style.

When your element has the `.active` class it will be set to `display: inline`, otherwise it'll be set to `display: none`.

---

If for whatever reason you don't want to use CSS here, you can use [jQuery's `css()` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/) instead to add `inline-block` into the element's `style` attribute:

```
$('ul:first', this).css({ display: 'inline' });
```

Comment: This will definitely work however the asker doesn't want to use CSS for some reason

Answer (score 1):

If you want a straight jquery method you can use

```
$("li.active").css("display","inline");
```